# Executable not running R6010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, windows-installer

I developed a project on VS 2010 using c++ qt. When I run the project in debug or release mode it works great. But what I want is to run it by double clicking on the generated executable, unfortunately when I do that I get a R6010 Error .. abort has been called.

I want to solve this problem to help me creating an installer for my project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to compare everything that is different between vc and regular run - I would start from comparing environment.

Comment: I'm pretty much a beginner in c++, so this is probably a stupid question .. the environment is the same so what else should I compare?

Comment: If it is the same, then you might still check if startup directory is the same for your VS run and regular one. If it is the same or if it doesn't matter to this error, then it gets more difficult. I would try to add some debug output (firstly in `main()` I guess), trying to see if your program starts to execute at all, and if then where it's execution stops. You need to run it from console though.

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me exactly the same, and the problem was that the executable was reading a configuration file and some image files that were not in the same directory as the executable, and obviously nonexistent program attempted to read files so the error occurred. What I did was copy the files that are read from my program to the same directory where the executable is found and everything was arranged. Check if this is your case. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same error, my solution was to debug and checking if specific call of C++ function reads or writes data out of range. In my case I was trying to access to element of STL container  that didn't exist.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/41485/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are running out of Virtual Address space. Possibly because you are making x86 binary and that is restricting the VA space that user mode process will get. Try using x64 binary. Memory management of Win 8.1 is much better than Win 7 (Win7 becomes unresponsive when footprint reaches GBs)