# Debug error R6010

Tags: c++

I've already searched online and none of it helped me. This is the code that's causing the error: Edited to include more code. Gives me the R6010 debug error in Visual Studio 2013.

```
do
{
    rLength = recv(s1, rBuf, 1, 0);
    if (rLength > 0)
    {
        rData += rBuf[0];
        if (rBuf[0] == nByte[0])
        {
            switch (rData[0])
            {
            case 'C':
                uid = rData.substr(1, 3);
                statSend = "00" + uid + "ST" + userinfo;
                charStat = statSend.c_str();
                lLength = send(s1, charStat, strlen(charStat) + 1, 0);
                break;
            case 'M':
                if (rData[4] == 'C' && rData[5] == 'H');
                {
                    size_t start = 6;
                    size_t end = rData.find("!@#$!@#&!@#*LlL");
                    size_t start2 = rData.find("*LlL");
                    size_t end2 = rData.find(";");

                    cout << rData.substr(start2, end2 - start2) << ":" << rData.substr(start, end - start) << endl;
                }
                break;
            }
            rData = "";
        }
    }
} while (rLength > 0);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Debug error R6010 - abort() has been called

Comment: Uhm, so this is, I'm guessing from the error message starting with R6... happening in Visual Studio? You don't really give us much context. What is `rData`? what is IN `rData`? Would it be possible to come up with a small, complete example of code that can be run by someone else?

Comment: This is happening in visual studio yes. I'm making a winsock application and rData is all the received data. I'll include the full code in my main post.

Comment: What does rData start as?  If it's a blank string, then if the first byte you get happens to match nByte[0] (whatever that is..) then I really think that in case 'M' you're running off the end of the one-byte rData, trying to access rData[4].

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess from what I can infer from your code.  When you call

```
rData.find("!@#$!@#&!@#*LlL");
```

...but it doesn't find that substring, then the variable start could be set to a random value.  (In my test program it was a huge integer.)

Then later you try to USE the (undefined) value stored in start to parse through the string again.

I suspect that's what you're seeing... an "out-of-bounds" error.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773630/executable-not-running-r6010).